# Wifi Drops out Intermittently only on Manjaro Laptop

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, manjaro

I am running an install of Manjaro on a Dell XPS 9560. Recently a problem has developed that is very annoying.

At random times throughout the day my wifi will drop out. It will not disconnect (it will show I am connected) however pings will fail to any domain. This only occurs on this laptop.

I have ran `dmesg` and noticed a bunch of blocks on DNS for multicast. As a result I did `ufw allow out dns` thinking perhaps this was the issue but it isn't. I have also tried to reinstall wpa-supplicant to no avail. I suspecting this was the case since I am connecting to a WPA network and it did not fix it. After adding the new UFW rules dmesg does not show anything unusual during the times the wifi drops out.

Running `sudo systemctl | grep network` gives me:

```
network-online.target                                                                  loaded active active    Network is Online                                                            
network.target                                                                         loaded active active    Network
```

And `sudo systemctl | grep net`

```
sys-devices-pciMY_DEVICE_ID-net-wlp2s0.device                     loaded active plugged   QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter                                    
sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlp2s0.device                                                loaded active plugged   QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter                                    
network-online.target                                                                  loaded active active    Network is Online                                                            
network.target                                                                         loaded active active    Network
```

A call to `networkctl` gives:

```
WARNING: systemd-networkd is not running, output will be incomplete.

IDX LINK   TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP    
  1 lo     loopback n/a         unmanaged
  2 wlp2s0 wlan     n/a         unmanaged
```

Tailing `journalctl` nothing looked super suspicious. There are a lot of calls to "Activating wireless network xyz <2 of 5>" but nothing else out of the ordinary.

From `lspci -k`

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
```

I am at a loss at what is causing this and it is very disruptive. Any guesses?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been `dhcpcd` conflicting with `dhclient`. By disabling `dhcpcd` and enabling `dhclient`, as well as configuring `NetworkManager` to use `dhclient` seems to have remedied the situation - at least temporarily. There were no indications this was the case in any of the logs.

I will report back if the problem persists. I hope this is fixed in a future release of Manjaro.

EDIT:

The problem is not fixed. However, rerunning `dhclient` when it dies fixes it. Very annoying. Rerunning `dhclient` occurs almost every hour.

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was with the kernel. I downgraded kernel from `5.15` to `4.19`.

Just changing kernel might fix the issue. Try that.

I tried 3 different kernels and 4.19 was the right one.

Additionally if that doesn't work, you could do one more thing, check which wifi-card you have `inxi -N` and download driver for your system.